# Use value of string for wide string when declaring constants in C++

Tags: c++, string, unicode, constants

Using defines I am able to declare a wide string that uses the value of regular string as follows:

```
#define MY_STRING "my value"
#define MY_WIDE_STRING L"" MY_STRING
```

How can I achieve the same but with member variables and a initialization list - i.e. something like this...

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
         const std::string MY_STRING
         const std::wstring MY_WIDE_STRING
    public:
         MyClass():MY_STRING("my value"), MY_WIDE_STRING(L"" MY_STRING)
         {
         }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
#define MY_VALUE "my value"

class MyClass
{
  private:
    const std::string MY_STRING
    const std::wstring MY_WIDE_STRING
  public:
    MyClass():MY_STRING(MY_VALUE), MY_WIDE_STRING(L"" MY_VALUE)
    {}
  // ...
};
```

I assume the reason you need both the `char` and `wchar_t` versions of the same string are because you're calling different libraries that you don't control.  Rather than keeping two copies of the string in sync, it's probably better to do a run-time conversion from one to the other when you must have the other version.

Comment: When the code is macro expanded, the compiler will see `MY_WIDE_STRING(L"" "my value")`. `L""` and `"my value` are separate literals of different data types. It is not guaranteed that the compiler will concatenate the quotes together before applying the `L` prefix to the final concatenated result.  To ensure concatenation, you have to use `L"my value"` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I'm not a language lawyer, but the standard says, "In translation phase 6 (2.2), adjacent string literals are concatenated. ... If one string literal has no _encoding-prefix_, it is treated as a string literal of the same _encoding-prefix_ as the other operand." [S2.14.5 P13]  That seems to suggest that this should work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You're not. `MY_STRING` is not a macro in this case, so you cannot use preprocessor concatenation.

If you think you need to store both strings, I recommend revisiting your design.

Comment: ok thanks. in that case how could I convert MY_STRING to MY_WIDE_STRING and keep it as a constant. Can this be done in the initialization list?

Comment: @fxfuture: No. Why do you think you need that?

Comment: i want to specify a single constant string value and have it available as a wide string to functions as soon as the class is instantiated so I don't have convert it each time

Comment: @fxfuture: Whydo you ever need to "convert it"? Why do you not stick with one or the other?

Comment: I have two different functions. one which processes strings and one which processes wide strings. i need "my value" available to use in both functions

Comment: @fxfuture: Fix your code so that the functions accept _consistent_ input.

Comment: i have to be able to process both a string variable and a wide string variable. i have no control over this. i was looking at this but it doesn't seem to help matters much -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846318/is-it-possible-to-have-a-c-method-accept-either-const-char-and-const-wchar-t

Comment: @fxfuture: _Why_ do you have to?

Comment: because i have both an ascii and a unicode variable that require processing - that's what i start with.  i am currently using an overloaded function to handle them individually.  those functions either contain regular functions such as std::string newString(oldString) or wide functions such as std::wstring newString(oldString) and they require my constant values in either regular or wide string format.

Comment: @fxfuture: You're not answering my question. I'm trying to determine how you have arrived at this unfortunate and smelly constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#define MY_VALUE "my value"

#define MAKE_WIDE_STRING_NX(S) L ## S
#define MAKE_WIDE_STRING(S) MAKE_WIDE_STRING_NX(S)

class MyClass
{
    private:
         const std::string _str;
         const std::wstring _wstr;
    public:
         MyClass(): _str(MY_VALUE), _wstr(MAKE_WIDE_STRING(MY_VALUE))
         {
         }
};
```