# template for char and wchar_t gives no matching member

Tags: c++, c, regex, templates

I've tried those 2 functions in order to deal with both char and wchar_t

[C++ count matches regex function that works with both char and wchar_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23644729/c-count-matches-regex-function-that-works-with-both-char-and-wchar-t)
[C++ regex with char and wchar_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622622/c-regex-with-char-and-wchar-t/23623610#23623610)

For my char* it works fine, but when it comes to use a wchar_t* it gives a no matching member function call. I don't understand why...

```
class myClass
{
    int occurrence = 0;
    string new_String;

public:


    template<typename CharType>
    void replaceSubstring(const CharType* find, const CharType* str, const CharType* rep)    {
        basic_string<CharType> text(str);
        basic_regex<CharType> reg(find);

       new_String = regex_replace(text, reg, rep);



    }

    template<typename CharT>
    void countMatches(const CharT* find, const CharT* str)
        {
            basic_string<CharT> text(str);
            basic_regex<CharT> reg(find);
            typedef typename basic_string<CharT>::iterator iter_t;
            occurrence = distance(regex_iterator<iter_t>(text.begin(), text.end(), reg),
                            regex_iterator<iter_t>());
        }


    void display()
    {
        cout << "occurrence " << occurrence << " new string " << new_String << endl;
    }

};



int main()
{

    const char *str1 = "NoPE NOPE noPE NoPE NoPE";
    const wchar_t *str2 = L"NoPE NOPE noPE NoPE NoPE";

    myClass test;


    test.countMatches("Ni",str1);
    test.replaceSubstring("No",str1,"NO");
    test.display();

    test.countMatches("Ni",str2);
    test.replaceSubstring("No",str2,"No");
    test.display();




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you paste the code?

Comment: posted. as you can see the function are right the same from the other 2 questions

Comment: where do you use `str1`?

Comment: sorry, renamed correctly

Comment: how about `test.countMatches(L"Ni",str2);` ?

Comment: same problem. no matching member function to call

Comment: The compiler errors already tell you what's going on - in particular, why it rejected the various overloads. Actually read them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `replaceSubstring()`, you're assigning the result of `regex_replace` with `basic_regex<ChartType>` into a `std::string`. This fails when `CharType` is not `char`, since then `std::string` has no such assignment operator.

In addition, you need to call the wide-character version with wide-character strings only, since its parameters have the same type. So:

```
test.countMatches(L"Ni",str2);
test.replaceSubstring(L"No",str2,L"No");
test.display();
```

Comment: but the error it's in both replaceSubstring than countMatches call.
It doesn't even get there

Comment: @UncleSax You never specified where the error occurs, nor given its full text, so it's kind of difficult to tell exactly. But I think I know the problem, I will add it to the answer.

Comment: it was specified in the questions. But you pointed out the problem! my mistake. thanks!

Comment: @UncleSax I'm glad it helped, but for the record, "no matching member function call" is *not* a complete error message. A complete error message would include at least the line number, and probably the name of the function it's trying to call (possibly applicable overloads as well).